# Build and write Json object of objects to file

Tags: arrays, go

I'm trying to take an array of strings that I receive from a Go API, and write them to a file in a weird json list format.  There are not brackets [], so i have to create a "dimension" for each of the string values in the array.  I'm trying to do this using types/structs, but i keep getting stuck (new at Go).  Should i try and just use maps, or is there a way to accomplish this?

This is the code I am using right now:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Dimension struct {
    SQL, Type string
}

type Measure struct {
    Type         string
    DrillMembers []string
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []string{"country", "year", "gdpPercap", "lifeExp", "pop", "continent"}
    cubeSchema := "measures: {\n  count: {\n    type: `count`,\n    drillMembers: "
    for i, s := range a {
        cubeSchema += s
        fmt.Println(cubeSchema)
        fmt.Println(i)
    }

    fileText := []byte(cubeSchema)
    fmt.Println(cubeSchema)
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("test.js", fileText, 0644)
    check(err)
}
```

This is how I need the output to look:

```
measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`,
      drillMembers: [country]
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    country: {
      sql: `country`,
      type: `string`
    },

    year: {
      sql: `year`,
      type: `string`
    },

    gdppercap: {
      sql: `gdppercap`,
      type: `string`
    },

    lifeexp: {
      sql: `lifeexp`,
      type: `string`
    },

    pop: {
      sql: `pop`,
      type: `string`
    },

    continent: {
      sql: `continent`,
      type: `string`
    }
  }
```

Right now I keep getting stuck with the following output:

```
measures: {
  count: {
    type: `count`,
    drillMembers: countryyeargdpPercaplifeExppopcontinent
```

Comment: "This is how I need the output to look" that's not JSON.

Comment: What format do you want the data to be in? It's neither JSON nor YAML. If you want to persist in a non-standardized format - you'll have to write custom code similar to what you've written. Also, I don't think it's going to be any easier with maps instead of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    schema := `measures: {
    count: {
      type: 'count',
      drillMembers: [country]
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
  `
    a := []string{"country", "year", "gdpPercap", "lifeExp", "pop", "continent"}
    var cubeSchema string
    for _, s := range a {
        cubeSchema += s + ": {\n\tsql: " + s + ",\n\ttype: `string`\n},\n"
    }

    fileText := []byte(schema + cubeSchema + "}\n}")
    fmt.Println(cubeSchema)
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("test.js", fileText, 0644)
    check(err)
}
```

check this code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the second part:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := []string{"country", "year", "gdpPercap", "lifeExp", "pop", "continent"}
    var items map[string]sqlType
    items = make(map[string]sqlType)

    for _, v := range a {
        items[v] = sqlType{SQL: v, Type: "string"}
    }

    dimensions := dimensions{Dimensions: items}

    bytes, err := json.Marshal(dimensions)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    c := string(bytes)

    fmt.Println(c)

}

type sqlType struct {
    SQL  string `json:"sql"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}

type dimensions struct {
    Dimensions map[string]sqlType `json:"dimensions"`
}
```